# Conservation of energy in superconducting transitions with Meissner effect

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, superconductivity

In Type I superconductors the transition from normal to superconducting state occurs exactly at its transition temperature.

Does this mean that we could theoretically use only a little bit of energy to "turn it on" and "off"?

When we have a magnet on top of a Type I superconductor that transitions, we observe the Meissner Effect (the magnet lifts up).

Example calculation of gravitational potential energy:
PE = 0.3kg * 9.81 m/s2 * 0.02m = 0.05886 J
300g magnet lifted 2 cm high is about 0.06 J.

Where does this energy come from?
Why is it always less than how much energy is required to make a transition occur? (Conservation of Energy)
Does transition take up more energy when there are magnetic fields inside the superconductor that have to be expelled?

Comment: We consider a gauge fix, where we set the phase associated with the hopping integral and the vector potential to be zero. We eventually find out for minimizing energy in the superconducting state, the only values the angles the canted AFM can take (this is the spontaneous symmetry broken state of the superconductor) directly sets the vector potential which happens to be proportional to the gradient of the potential (and hence, $B=\nabla\times A = 0$. There is no KE, magnetic fields are being expelled as a consequence of the requirement that the canted AFM can assume only certain (Euler) angles

Comment: We can see the magnet move, we can even calculate how its gravitational potential potential energy increases as it lifts up. The question is how the increase in that relates to the energy required to make a state change.

Comment: When "ordinary" electrons condense into Cooper pairs, energy is released, as can be seen by the increase in electronic specific heat at the transition temperature, $T_0$.  When $T<<T_0$ there are few free quasi-particles and the specific heat falls below that of a normal metal.  This condensation energy provides free energy to drive out the magnetic field.

Comment: i think it does not lift up it only keeps it at high you put in. so if you put magnet on top of a super conductor just above $T_C$ magnet will stay in touch, and if you go below $T_C$ it will remain touching it wont magically lift up.but if you put in some height  at sc phase it will stay at that heigth. so you are not creating potential energy just by shifting phase of sc.

Comment: @physshyp https://youtu.be/HRLvVkkq5GE demonstration

Comment: Well it keeps cooling it if it leaves the temp infitesmalyy smaller than t critical it would levitate infinitesamlly.  As it cools the ammount of b field decrase in sc and strength of meisner effect increases.